# Handling Android back button in a particular place - Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, dom

I am developing a mobile app using Cordova and Intel's Appframework.

I would like to take control over the Android hardware back button to direct to some other page (after form submission I don't want the user to go back to the form. Instead I want to direct them to some other page).

And I want to exit the app when the user is on the home div (#home).

As I learnt from the cordova/Cordova documentation, I should add an event listener to the DOM as follows.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

But this adds an universal event whenever the back button is pressed, the event triggers (I have tried it).

In Intel Appframework, I can load a function on panel by declaring the function to `data-load` attribute.

How can I load the backbutton function only to a particular div ?

I hope it's clear. Please let me know if further clarification needed.

Answer (score 1):

Register the event listener, and then check for your div when the event fires. I am not quite sure what you mean by "How can I load the backbutton function only to a particular div?" But I am assuming you mean the div is visible or it has focus in some way... you can check for whatever constitutes "load ... to a particular div" in an IF statement within the onBackKeyDown function.

```
// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
  // Register the event listener
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}


// Handle the back button
function onBackKeyDown() {
  if (--check for your event criteria here--){ -- do what you want here--}
  else {
      if (window.confirm("Exit the application?")) {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I meant to say panel divs (represented as page in single page apps).

Comment: So you can test to see if a particular panel is visible, and then hide and show the appropriate panel divs.